# Fade bottom of UIScrollView to transparent

Tags: uiscrollview, calayer

I have a UIScrollView, and I need the bottom to fade to transparent, so that it does not abruptly cut off the content. The background of the UIScrollView is a custom color. This is what I have so far, but the layer is showing up white, instead of the custom color. This is what I am going for, but only on the bottom.

:[image: This is what I am going for, but only on the bottom]

Here is what I have so far:

```
maskLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

            CGColorRef firstColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141 green:211 blue:244 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
            CGColorRef secondColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141 green:211 blue:244 alpha:0.8].CGColor;
            CGColorRef thirdColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141 green:211 blue:244 alpha:0.2].CGColor;
            CGColorRef fourthColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:141 green:211 blue:244 alpha:0.0].CGColor;

            maskLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)firstColor, (__bridge id)secondColor, (__bridge id)thirdColor, (__bridge id)fourthColor, nil];
            maskLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0],
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.2],
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.8],
                                                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];
            maskLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 285, self.loginScrollView.frame.size.width, 40);
            maskLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
            [self.loginScrollView.layer addSublayer:maskLayer];
```

For some reason, the layer is showing up as white, and only half the width of the scrollView.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The approach I used was to subclass `UIScrollView`, and create the mask layer in the `layoutSubviews` method.

Here's my code, which fades the top and bottom of the `UIScrollView` from the background colour to transparent:

```
#import "FadingScrollView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

static float const fadePercentage = 0.2;

@implementation FadingScrollView

// ...

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    NSObject * transparent = (NSObject *) [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0] CGColor];
    NSObject * opaque = (NSObject *) [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor];

    CALayer * maskLayer = [CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds;

    CAGradientLayer * gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, 0,
                                     self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);

    gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: transparent, opaque,
                            opaque, transparent, nil];

    // Set percentage of scrollview that fades at top & bottom
    gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fadePercentage],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0 - fadePercentage],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], nil];

    [maskLayer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer;
}

@end
```

If you just want to fade the bottom, change this line:

```
// Fade bottom of scrollview only
gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0 - fadePercentage],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], nil];
```

When I was implementing this myself, I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866343/fading-out-any-content-which-approaches-edges-of-uiscollview) helpful, and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kgn/3180607) on github.

**EDIT:** I've put this code up on github, see [here](https://github.com/stephsharp/SSFadingScrollView).

Comment: I think that now it should be UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn used there.

Answer (score 12):

Really like Steph Sharp's implementation, I converted it to swift and thought I'd share in case anyone else needs it.

```
let fadePercentage = CGFloat(0.2)

override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    var transparent = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    var opaque = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor

    var maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds

    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height)
    gradientLayer.colors = [transparent, opaque, opaque, transparent]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, fadePercentage, 1 - fadePercentage, 1]

    maskLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer

}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here goes the swift 3 version of Steph's answer:

```
let fadePercentage: Double = 0.2

override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    let transparent = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    let opaque = UIColor.black.cgColor

    let maskLayer = CALayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: 0, width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
    gradientLayer.colors = [transparent, opaque, opaque, transparent]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0, NSNumber(floatLiteral: fadePercentage), NSNumber(floatLiteral: 1 - fadePercentage), 1]

    maskLayer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer

}
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me a little time.

Answer (score 0):

Theres also  **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262188/2242359)** answer which does not include any subclassing.