# uitableview fade out cell when going under header like the Yahoo Mail App

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

So basically I'm trying to do a table view with sections, exactly like the new Yahoo Mail app does in it's transparent side menu (notice how the cells fadeout when they get under the table section header)

I'm currently thinking into doing some calculations in scrollViewDidScroll, and check if a cell will go under the table header section (when the header is stuck at the screen top) and start fading in or out the cell that's passing under the table header section, but that could get really tedious at some point, so maybe there's another elegant way of doing this?

**So the actual question is** how can I progressively fade out a tableview cell when it's going under it's section header, and fade it back in when it's going in the reverse direction, and coming visually from under the table view section header

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CAGradientLayer to your view with a gradient at top and set as a mask. It gives the desired effect with very fluid results.

See the third response to the following post:

[How to create a top fade effect using UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774761/how-to-create-a-top-fade-effect-using-uiscrollview)